# Is the plus/minus sign internationalized?

Tags: c++, stl, localization, internationalization, iostream

I've been looking for a way to add my own custom sign character to positive and negative numbers, but there doesn't seem to be a standard way to do so. Is the plus minus sign internationalized in IOStreams? The closest thing I could find to overriding it is the `positive_sign()`/`negative_sign()` functions in [`std::moneypunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/moneypunct) but that is only for monetary data. Something like this would seem appropriate for [`std::numpunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign character is obtained using `std::ctype<cT>::widen(s)` where `s` is the sign character. There is no custom, default way to change the sign character specifically by just overriding a specific member function. However, it is reasonably straight forward to create a custom `std::num_put<...>` or `std::num_get<...>` using whatever other sign characters. The reason the decimal point and the thousands separator are treated different is that they are embedded somewhere in the actual value and it isn't that easy to create a special version of the code.

Comment: Do you know the reason why there are no plus minus functions in the numpunct facet?

Comment: @0x499602D2: the main reasons I can think of is the one already stated (it is easy to customize already) and possibly that it is rarely required: off-hand I'm unaware of any language which uses a different sign (which is unlike decimal points and thousands separators, for example: the German notation uses comma for the decimal point and dot for the thousands separators). The localization facilities where primarily mimicking those use for C and doing what was explicitly required.

Comment: According to information accessible via http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/number-symbols some languages have “+” preceded by LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK, and there a few different settings for the minus sign, though the latter data appears to be unreliable (it partly depends on whether people defining it for each language understood the difference between HYPHEN-MINUS and MINUS SIGN). There is apparently *need* for internationalizing plus sign and minus sign.